# Unexpected Non-Void Return Value In Void Function (Swift 2.0)

Tags: swift, closures, nsurlsession

I have been skimming the StackOverflow questions trying to figure out where I'm going wrong with my code, but I just can't seem to!  I am trying to convert my Swift 1.2 project to Swift 2.0, and am having an issue with my class that downloads JSON data.

I am continually receiving the error **Unexpected non-void return value in void function**.

Here is the code, somewhat truncated, that I am using;

```
...

class func fetchMinionData() -> [Minion] {

    var myURL = "http://myurl/test.json"

    let dataURL = NSURL(string: myURL)

    let request = NSURLRequest(URL: dataURL!, cachePolicy: .ReloadIgnoringLocalAndRemoteCacheData, timeoutInterval: 5.0)

    let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()

    session.dataTaskWithRequest(request, completionHandler: {(data, response, error) in
        let minionJSON = JSON(data!)

        var minions = [Minion]()

        for (_, minionDictionary) in minionJSON {
            minions.append(Minion(minionDetails: minionDictionary))
        }

        return minions
        //THIS IS WHERE THE ERROR OCCURS

    }).resume()
}

...
```

Perhaps I am overlooking something simple, but I'm unsure why my function would be considered void at all.  Any thoughts would be immensely appreciated!  Thank you!

Answer (score 57, accepted):

You have a problem because your line:

```
return minions
```

does not return from your function. Instead, it returns from the completion handler in `dataTaskWithRequest`. And it shouldn't be doing so because that closure is a void function.

The problem which you have results from the fact that `dataTaskWithRequest` is an asynchronous operation. Which means that it can return later after executing your function.

So, you need to change your design pattern.

One way of doing that would be the following:

```
static var minions:[Minion] = [] {
    didSet {
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("minionsFetched", object: nil)
   }
}



class func fetchMinionData() {

    var myURL = "http://myurl/test.json"
    let dataURL = NSURL(string: myURL)
    let request = NSURLRequest(URL: dataURL!, cachePolicy: .ReloadIgnoringLocalAndRemoteCacheData, timeoutInterval: 5.0)

    let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()

    session.dataTaskWithRequest(request, completionHandler: {(data, response, error) in
        let minionJSON = JSON(data!)

        var minions = [Minion]()

        for (_, minionDictionary) in minionJSON {
            minions.append(Minion(minionDetails: minionDictionary))
        }

        self.minions = minions
        //THIS IS WHERE THE ERROR OCCURS

    }).resume()
}
```

Then before calling your function you should register to listen for `NSNotification` with name "minionsFetched". And only after you get that notification you should process the minions as if they were fetched.

Comment: That makes sense to me.  But if I move the `return minions` line to after `}).resume()`, which is where I think it should go, I receive the error **Use of unresolved identifier minions**.  Which I can't seem to grasp how to resolve!

Comment: thanks @AndriyGordiychuk Gordiychuk for the very important line You have a problem because your line:

return minions
does not return from your function. Instead, it returns from the completion handler in dataTaskWithRequest

Answer (score 24):

I fixed mine by creating a completion handler. You can do this instead of using notifications:

```
class func fetchMinionData(completionHandler: (minions: [Minion]) -> Void) {

    var myURL = "http://myurl/test.json"

    let dataURL = NSURL(string: myURL)

    let request = NSURLRequest(URL: dataURL!, cachePolicy: .ReloadIgnoringLocalAndRemoteCacheData, timeoutInterval: 5.0)

    let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()

    session.dataTaskWithRequest(request, completionHandler: {(data, response, error) in
        let minionJSON = JSON(data!)

        var minions = [Minion]()

        for (_, minionDictionary) in minionJSON {
            minions.append(Minion(minionDetails: minionDictionary))
        }

        completionHandler(minions: minions)
        //THIS IS WHERE YOUR PREVIOUS ERROR OCCURRED

    }).resume()
}
```

Comment: Way to revive a 4-year-old answer, but don't we have to make the closure `@escaping` since the function scope will be completed before the async call?