# Return Firebase query results from function for UIViewcontroller

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, return-type

I'm new to Swift object oriented dev in general. I'm trying to load the query results from Firebase into a ViewController.  I'm struggling with get the QuerySnapShot into an object to be used as the source for the View Controller.  Specifically, I keep getting a "Unexpected non-void return value in void function" error where the return statement is.  Any ideas?  It there's a better way to do this in general please let me know.  Any help is much appreciated.

// MARK:  - API

```
func getBoxContents() -> Dictionary<String, Any> {
    // Get user data to populate collection view
    let userRef = db.collection("documents")
    var userData: Array<Dictionary<String,Any>> = []

    userRef.whereField("email", isEqualTo: userEmail!).getDocuments() { (querySnapshot, err) in
        if let err = err {
            print("Error getting documents: \(err)")
        } else {
            for document in querySnapshot!.documents {
                var userData = document.data()
                print("\(document.documentID) => \(document.data())")
            }
            return userData
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your `return userData` is trying to return a value out of the closure it runs in, which is not possible. Since `getDocument()` runs asynchronously, you can't `return` any results from the database out of `getBoxContents`. Instead you'll want to pass in your own closure/completion handler, similar to the `{ (querySnapshot, err) in` that `getDocuments()` takes as a parameter. See for an example: https://stackoverflow.com/q/38469648/209103

Comment: Thank you @FrankvanPuffelen, that was the issue and it lead me to do some more reading on Completion handlers and initializing objects.  Thanks again!

Comment: Great to her that you got it working Ben! I closed your question against the one I linked earlier.

Comment: One more question more related to how to use this message board.  Should I have closed the question as answered?  I looked for a way to do it but couldn't find anywhere to.

Comment: You could have posted your solution as an answer. But since you didn't post an answer and it sounds like you implemented what's in the answer I linked, I closed it as a duplicate.