# Function gives Unexpected non-void return value in void function

Tags: swift

I have a function that is supposed to get json data and return it. This is the function below:

```
func httpjson(){
    let requestURL: NSURL = NSURL(string: "http://www.learnswiftonline.com/Samples/subway.json")!
    let urlRequest: NSMutableURLRequest = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: requestURL)
    let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
    let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(urlRequest) { (data, response, error) -> Void in
        let httpResponse = response as! NSHTTPURLResponse
        let statusCode = httpResponse.statusCode
        if (statusCode == 200) {
            print("All OK!")
            do{
                let json = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options:.AllowFragments)
                return json
            }catch {
                print("Error with Json: \(error)")
            }
        }
    }
    task.resume()
}
```

The code returns the error `Unexpected non-void return value in void function`

After reading a little about this issue, I read that this can be fixed by changing `func httpjson(){` to `func httpjson()-> String{` but it still returns the same error.

Comment: Very similar to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/32121108/6541007).

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be with your closure that's defined as `(data, response, error) -> Void`, not with the `httpjson` method.

Since your data task is asynchronous, `httpjson` has already returned by the time the JSON parsing finishes.  It doesn't need to be defined as returning anything because there's nothing **to** return yet.

You need to do something with `json` (notification, callback, completion block, ...) to let the rest of your app know when it's ready to use.