# Swift: Loading JSON data from a URL

Tags: json, swift

I am attempting to modify Apple's code from the Landmarks tutorial to load JSON data from a remote URL. The url is a php script which returns plaintext JSON data.

Apple's code:

```
func loadLocalJSON<T: Decodable>(_ filename: String) -> T {
    let data: Data
    
    guard let file = Bundle.main.url(forResource: filename, withExtension: nil)
        else {
            fatalError("Couldn't find \(filename) in main bundle")
    }
    
    do {
        data = try Data(contentsOf: file)
    } catch {
        fatalError("Couldn't load \(filename) from main bundle:\n\(error)")
    }
    
    do {
        let decoder = JSONDecoder()
        return try decoder.decode(T.self, from: data)
    } catch {
        fatalError("Couldn't parse \(filename) from main bundle:\n\(error)")
    }
}
```

And my code as currently modified:

```
func loadRemoteJSON<T: Decodable>(_ urlString: String) -> T {
    let data: Data
    
    guard let url = URL(string: urlString) else {
        fatalError("Invalid URL")
    }
    
    let request = URLRequest(url: url)
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
        guard let data = data else {
            fatalError(error?.localizedDescription ?? "Unknown Error")
        }
        
        do {
            let decoder = JSONDecoder()
            return try decoder.decode(T.self, from: data) // <--ERROR HERE
        } catch {
            fatalError("Couldn't parse data from \(urlString)\n\(error)")
        }
    }
}
```

The error I am getting is `Unexpected non-void return value in void function`

I thought the function was supposed to be returning an instance of T. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: "The error I am getting is Unexpected non-void return value in void function"  Where!?

Comment: Your URL session has something missing.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unexpected Non-Void Return Value In Void Function (Swift 2.0)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32121108/unexpected-non-void-return-value-in-void-function-swift-2-0)

Comment: I think you need a completion block instead of a return. If you go with a new async-await then return is fine but this code is not for that.

Comment: I agree with @RajaKishan-you shouldn't use a return if you're running an async task, you risk having the value of your variable initialized with `loadRemoteJSON` be nil since Swift will move forward through your code without awaiting the initialization of that variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a completion block instead of a return type. You are doing the async task. `URLSession.shared.dataTask` is async type.

```
func loadRemoteJSON<T: Decodable>(_ urlString: String, completion: @escaping  ((T) -> Void)) {
    let data: Data
    
    guard let url = URL(string: urlString) else {
        fatalError("Invalid URL")
    }
    
    let request = URLRequest(url: url)
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
        guard let data = data else {
            fatalError(error?.localizedDescription ?? "Unknown Error")
        }
        
        do {
            let decoder = JSONDecoder()
            let data = try decoder.decode(T.self, from: data)
            completion(data)
        } catch {
            fatalError("Couldn't parse data from \(urlString)\n\(error)")
        }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
struct TestModel: Decodable {
    var name: String
}

loadRemoteJSON("urlstring") { (data: TestModel) in
    print(data.name)
}
```

If you are using Swift 5.5 then you can return your data by using  Async Await. There many articles and videos are available on the net. You can check [this](https://alfianlosari.medium.com/using-swift-5-5-async-await-to-fetch-rest-api-cb1e4043b55c).

Answer (score 1):

```
func loadRemoteJSON<T: Decodable>(_ urlString: String,completion: @escaping (T)->Void)
```

Using the completion block is simple, just decode the JSON and pass it into your completion handler.

```
let decodedJSON = try decoder.decode(T.self, from: data)
completion(decodedJSON)
```

Now, when you call `loadRemoteJSON`, you'll be able to access the JSON inside of the function's completion block, like:

```
loadRemoteJSON(urlString: someString){ data in
 //data is your returned value of the generic type T.
}
```